# Using pci-stub to reserve one of the two identical GPUs

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

So I'm trying to set up Xen for my system, which has 2 HD 5670 GPUs. I want to allocate one of the cards to the virtual machine, but I also want to keep using the open source radeon driver, which binds to all GPUs. I want to prevent that behaviour by using pci-stub, but it only accepts vendor:device IDs, so with same devices, I can't use that.
How would I either

a) Make pci-stub reserve one of the two identical devices

b) Configure the radeon driver in a way that it only uses the first GPU.

I'm using the tutorial over at http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=112013.
The hypervisor is running Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

In step 8 of the tutorial you quoted, the following is said:

> Enter the following command to list your graphics adapters' PCI IDs:
>   lspci | grep VGA

This command lists all your VGA adapters, and you will get different IDs for those, because they are in different slots.

And then you can either hide the device on boot using `xen-pciback` module's `hide`option, or unbind the device and then allocate it to the domU you want.